# AppDynamics iOS block my request and response nil

Tags: ios, sdk, monitoring, document, appdynamics

I implement AppDynamics in my iOS app, I put everything in doc 
 like initWithKey licence key, but if I write initWithKey in appDelegate my all service request return nil. Can anyone help me Thank you.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Yeah but its a weird situation,  actually I have another framework, use for networking and analytcs this library and Appdynamics request conflicts each other if you use another framework about networking delete and try again you will get response I guess.